# Finding the Jordan form for a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

$$A:= \begin{bmatrix}4 & -4 & -11 & 11\\3 & -12 & -42 & 42\\ -2 & 12 &  37 & -34 \\ -1 & 7 & 20 & -17  \end{bmatrix}$$

I'm struggling with this matrix: it has $p_A(x) = (x-3)^4 $, yet $\ker(A - 3I)^3 $ is already the whole space $ \mathbb C^4 $. I read on another post that (for the $ \mathbb C^3 $ case of a similar matrix) I should take this to be the size of the biggest Jordan block, thus leaving me with $1$ standard eigenvector and a Jordan chain (image of the image of $\ldots$ ) of a vector $v$ **not** in $\ker(A - 3I)^2$. But this doesn't work for any $v$.

What steps should I follow to find the Jordan form of $A$?

Comment: @JonathanHebert thanks for the information. But if you're referring to $Ker(A - 3I)^3$, does that mean it's diagonal? 4 Jordan Blocks $<-->$ diagonal

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was confusinf, I will write an answer below.

Comment: Do. Not. Reask the same question!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please understand that I really needed an answer and that, when I was actually able to edit my question, enough people had downvoted it for it to seem like a bad/uninteresting one (which I hope it's not!). And no one had made the effort to change the few things that had to be edited either.

Answer (score 2):

It maybe of interest to have the explicit decomposition

$A=PJP^{-1}$ with

$$J=\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}3  &   1   &  0   &  0\\
     0   &  3  &   1  &   0\\
     0   &  0  &   3  &  0\\ \hline
     0   &  0  &   0  &   3\end{array}\right) \ \ \text{and} \ \ P=\begin{pmatrix} 
     \ \ 3   &  3  &  14  &   0\\
     \ \ 9   &  0   &  0   &  0\\
    -6   &  6  &   1  &   1\\
    -3   &  6  &   0   &  1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Let $B=A-3I_4$. We have $\ker(B) \subsetneqq \ker(B^2) \subsetneqq
\ker(B^3)$ with:

$\ker(B)=\langle \begin{pmatrix} 
     0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
     2\\6\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}\rangle, \ \ \ker(B^2)=\langle \begin{pmatrix} 
     0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
     2\\6\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
     1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\rangle, \ \ \ker(B^3)=\mathbb{R}^4.$

Comment: P is what I'm interested in! How do I obtain the basis vectors?

Comment: For example, the last column $C$ of $P$ is such that $(A-3I_4)C=0$Then you have to find a $D, D \neq C$ such that $(A-3I_4)^2D=0$...

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the method you're trying to apply is not quite right. My guess is that the result that is attempted to being applied is that "the algebraic multiplicity of $3$ in the minimal polynomial of your matrix is the size of the largest Jordan block". (you're looking at the geometric multiplicity of your eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial instead).

This is true, and it's also true that the minimal polynomial is $(x-3)^{3}$. This tells me that the size of the largest Jordan block is $3$.

Once you've applied this, we're done, we only have one eigenvalue, the largest Jordan block is of size $3$, the dimension of our space is $4$, we only have room for one more block, so we know what the Jordan Canonical form is (right?).